# Using comma-separated value for looping through data with sumifs/vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet, where I have a lot of raw book-keeping data with "accounts" as an identifier.

Now I want to make "sum rows" in another sheet, where I keep a list of accounts in a cell as a comma-separated value. What I want is for this comma-separated value to be looped for all the "raw data" and then have the amount from the bookkeeping of ALL entries for these accounts summed.

Example:

RAW DATA:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1.25 |
| 1000 | 1.75 |
| 1000 | 100.22 |
| 2422 | 29.00 |
| 2400 | 20.00 |

Sum sheet:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1000,2400 | 123.22 |
| 2422 | 29.00 |
| 2400,2422 | 49.00 |

I have tried with the following formula, but it doesnt seem to sum all of the accounts - only the first one in each comma-separated list.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Accounts!F:F;Accounts!A:A;TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2;",";REPT(" ";9999));(ROW($BB$1:INDEX($BB:$BB;LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;",";""))+1))-1)*9999+1;9999))))))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `match()`? p.s. an example sheet would be nice

Comment: @Argyll oh sorry - I didnt know I could share an example sheet. Will try to figure out how - thx for the tip :)

Comment: If you are thinking about anonymous sharing, last time I check, the only way is to use a throwaway gmail account. I usually create examples with my main account but just delete the link after answers are in.  Aside, I just double checked: `match()` seems to require whole cell-to-cell match. `REGEXMATCH()` works though and is `arrayformula` compatible for `sumproduct()` later. Like `arrayformula(regexmatch(A1,'Sheet 1'!A1:A2))`

Comment: If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=SPLIT(D1,","))*(B:B))
```